# Como reiniciar las conexiones de sql en php

Tags: php, sql

Estoy programando un sistema en php que se conecta a `sql`, pero se ha hecho muy frecuente que me salga este mensaje de error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1040): Too many connections in
>   /home/u442095798/public_html/conexion.php on line 5 Conexion Fallida :
>   Too many connections

Al investigar en internet encontré que se puede ver las conexiones se puede escribir en `SQL` el siguiente comando:

```
show status like '%onn%';
```

Muestra que se han utilizado 175342417 conexiones, este numero de conexiones se incrementa aunque el sitio web no este abierto.

No he podido encontrar una solución al problema de conexiones.

¿Podrían indicarme si es posible reiniciar los valores de las conexiones desde php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las librerías PDO ([asignando a `null` la variable](http://php.net/pdo.connections)) y MySQLi ([`mysqli::close()`](http://php.net/mysqli.close)) permiten cerrar las conexiones tras ser usadas. Por norma general se cierran automáticamente tras la finalización del script.

Si estás usando un servidor dedicado deberías averiguar desde dónde se establecen las conexiones con un [`SHOW [FULL] PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html) para descartar una posible toma de tu servidor. En el listado te aparecerá la IP o host desde el que se establece la conexión así como el usuario que han usado para ello.

Si estás usando un alojamiento compartido es probable que el problema no sea tuyo, si no del proveedor que te da servicio. Quizá ha hecho un mal dimensionamiento del servidor, deberías reclamarlo para que lo arreglen.

Por favor, no uses ni las conexiones persistentes de [`mysql_pconnect()`](http://php.net/mysql_pconnect) como te han recomendado ni, en general, las funciones `mysql_*`. Fueron marcadas como obsoletas en [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/migration55.deprecated) y eliminadas completamente en [PHP 7.0](http://php.net/changelog.mysql), principalmente porque son fuente de agujeros de seguridad y fuente de malas prácticas.

Si me confirmas si tu servidor es dedicado o compartido podré seguir ayudándote en más profundidad.

Comment: estoy utilizando un servidor hostinger que segun entiendo esta en la nube o algo así, con respecto al show [FULL] processlist lo cheque y me muestra solo un proceso, en general el servicio es muy bueno de verdad recomiendo este servidor hostinger porque es gratuito pero con respecto a las conexiones segun tengo 1000 conexiones disponibles y no he utilizado mas de 100 y aun asi me marca el error, tal vez algo se me esta pasando, por ello pense que se podría reiniciar los valores de las conexiones utilizadas desde php cada cierto tiempo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si sólo ves un proceso es porque no tienes privilegios en la base de datos para ver las conexiones. Es decir, no tienes un servidor dedicado sólo para ti, es compartido. Al ser compartido las conexiones que están saturando el servidor MySQL es la suma de todos los usuarios del alojamiento compartido, por lo que tú no puedes hacer nada para arreglar ese problema, sólo hostinger.

Comment: La verdad eso era algo que pensaba que podría pasar como explicación razonable pero me negaba a aceptar, pero en fin, crees que si compro una cuenta premium con este servidor esto cambie?

Comment: Lo siento, desconozco la calidad de servicio de ese proveedor. Yo administro servidores propios (dedicados), y dimensiono el límite de conexiones según la carga que tienen los servidores con el paso del tiempo. Quizá deberías mirar alternativas como contratar VPS con paneles de control sencillos de administrar. Así los recursos consumidos son únicamente por ti. Consulta al servicio de atención al usuario de hostinger si tendrás ese problema con el servicio premium o no... quizá también sea bueno que le digas que tienes actualmente el problema, para que traten de solucionarlo.

Comment: Asi lo hare Bro, muchas gracias por tu apoyo, la verdad estoy días fueron un quebradero de cabeza porque no podía solucionarlo, como última pregunta sabes porque el valor de session en php no se ve en jquery, te paso el link del ejemplo de un buscador que es muy util pero quiero agregarle valores con sesiones pero el contenido no llega.                  http://www.yoelprogramador.com/buscador-instantaneo-con-php-mysql-y-jquery/#comment-4064

Comment: Recuerda que debes hacer un `session_start()` primero... pero sin código no puedo decirte qué te está fallando.

Comment: En este link puedes encontrar el código, no trae el session_start() pero yo si lo he agregado a mis scripts pero no funciona             http://www.yoelprogramador.com/buscador-instantaneo-con-php-mysql-y-jquery/#comment-4064

Comment: Inicializo las sesiones desde el login, y he comprobado que se muestran en todos los programas excepto en este de busqueda, he intentado de muchas formas pero no lo quiere captar.

Comment: La sesión debe comenzarse antes de enviar nada al navegador y en todos los archivos: los que crean, modifican y/o leen las variables de sesión. Estaré un día o dos sin acceso a un ordenador para poder intentar reproducir tu problema con las variables de sesión. Mientras te recomiendo que abras un tema nuevo, es muy probable que otra persona pueda ayudarte entre tanto. Suerte.

Comment: Esta bien Bro, lo checare, saludos y bendiciones.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias usar conexiones persistentes al mysql

`mysql_pconnect()` [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-pconnect.php)

Estas permiten que hagas una conexion permanenta al servidor de Mysql

Otra cosa que podrias hacer seria cambiar el tiempo de la variable `interactive_timeout` de Mysql. Ya que puede pasar que algun proceso este durando mas tiempo del necesario y deje la conexion de Mysql activa.

[Interactive Timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html)

Comment: voy a checar las opciones que propones, muchas gracias por tu apoyo, por cierto y aprovechando el presente mensaje, sabes porque las Sessiones en php se pierden al pasar por un proceso de busqueda en ajax?  es muy raro porque en php me aparece su valor pero al momento de ir al programa que tiene ajax y java no me muestra nada, nuevamente gracias, saludos.

Comment: este es el link del programa en java y ajax que te comente   http://www.yoelprogramador.com/buscador-instantaneo-con-php-mysql-y-jquery/#comment-4064

Comment: Perdon es jquery y no java segun veo.

Comment: No estaras incluyendo algun fichero que este eliminando la sesion, o bien que haga un unset de la variable $_SESSION?

Comment: No Bro la verdad no utilizo unset, lo extraño es que cuando vuelvo a php resulta que la session si tiene valor, quizas si bajas el ejemplo del link que te mande sea mas facil determinar la situación, he solucionado este dilema con una mexicanada definitivamente que no me gusto porque no es muy practico, por ello me gustaria solucionar la situacion de las sesiones o bien poder pasar mas de un valor de variable en jquery porque el ejemplo solo me permite mandar un valor en la variable b, muchas gracias Bro.